# Unity5 Instantiate scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a Scriptable Object with [CreateAssetMenu] option in the editor and it's called 'Assets/MyCard1.asset'. In there, I have specified some values like name, sprite, attack, health etc.

So my goal is to spawn a deck of 30 cards based on the same Prefab, but when I use 'Instantiate(gamobject)', it spawns a gameobject with default Prefab parameters. How do I assign 'Assets/MyCard[i].asset' data to EACH of newly spawned cards (with code)? I can do that with Inspector just fine by dragging Asset to the Prefab's script component.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Card", menuName = "Card")]
public class CardScriptable : ScriptableObject
{
    public new string name;
    public string description;

    public Sprite artwork;

    public int manaCost;
    public int attack;
    public int health;
}


public class SpawnStuff : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;  
    GameObject[] tempKarta = new GameObject[30];

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            tempKarta[i] = Instantiate(myPrefab);
            temp.Karta[i]. ?? DRAW_DATA_FROM "Assets/MyCard1.asset" (); // ??
        }

    }
}
```

Is my approach rational? If not, what is a better approach to this?

UPD:
Here's my presets, and prefab[image]

[image]

[image]

also script that just displays stuff from CardScriptable

```
public class CardDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CardScriptable card;

    public Text nametext;
    public Text descriptionText;

    public Image artworkImage;

    public Text manaText;
    public Text attackText;
    public Text healthText;

    void Awake()
    {
        nametext.text = card.name;
        descriptionText.text = card.description;

        artworkImage.sprite = card.artwork;

    }

}
```

Comment: what is `kartonka` pretty unclear in your code what you are trying to achieve exactly ...

Comment: sorry, it's myPrefab actually. let me edit that.

Comment: Could you also include how this prefab looks like exactly / what you want to do with your data from the scriptable object?

Comment: included some screenshots. Basically those assets contain data that I want to include in newly instantiated objects. I can drag them in inspector but not in code.

Comment: You’re really using unity5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allready have your structure. All you would need is not do your stuff in `Awake` but rather have a method for it like

```
public class CardDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text nametext;
    public Text descriptionText;

    public Image artworkImage;

    public Text manaText;
    public Text attackText;
    public Text healthText;

    public void Initialize(CardScriptable card)
    {
        nametext.text = card.name;
        descriptionText.text = card.description;

        artworkImage.sprite = card.artwork;

    }
}
```

Then have e.g. an array of `CardScriptable[]` in

```
public class SpawnStuff : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Rather make this of the correct type!
    public CardDisplay myPrefab;  
    private CardDisplay[] tempKarta = new CardDisplay[30];

    // Adjust in Inspector
    public CardScriptable[] availableCardConfigs;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var config = availableCardConfigs[Random.Range(0, availableCardConfigs.Length)];
            // If you make the prefab of correct type this already returns a CardDisplay
            tempKarta[i] = Instantiate(myPrefab);
            tempKarta[i].Initialize(config);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I've been looking for, thanks a lot! One question, is it ok to have my entire collection of 300+ cards in this array of the script? Or should there be another way to store cards (there might be some cards spawned that did not start in the deck, for example). If it's reasonable then fine!

Comment: currently from the array it only takes 30 random cards (including duplicates!). You could define your ways as you like in order to take only certain cards from there or not ;) I would have them all in one place and then maybe filter on certain values ... you could e.g. give them an enum like `enum Cardtype { CharacterCard, MagicSpell, Effect, etc }`

Answer (score 1):

After a few more details were added I think I have a handle on the issue.

You can create another ScriptableObject class which is used as a collection to avoid any external file issues which you may be having eg

```
Public class Deck : ScriptableObject {
    Public CardScriptable[] cards;
}
```

Comment: Ok I see, so instead of those assets I should create a class that will hold whole card collection right? https://imgur.com/a/wwJO3hs

Answer (score 0):

ScriptableObjects can have methods of their own. The typical method I use in this situation is to make a method on your script able object to instantiate the cards and assign values there as opposed to instantiating the cards that way.

Edit: possible misinterpretation on my part, if the problem is you cannot easily change the text/sprites etc. I would make a handler class to put on your card prefab which holds references to where you need once instantiated.

That way you can use for eg GetComponent().sprite = newSprite;

Comment: But my public variables of CardScriptable class are empty. I mean, it's not 'CardScriptable.cs' that contains sprite image and other data, but this asset that cannot be opened with Visual Studio. How do I draw data from .asset file created from asset menu in code, not in inspector?